# Error INSTALL_FAILED_PACKAGE_CHANGED when installing app using adb install

Tags: android, adb, android-source

When I'm trying to update an app using adb install command, I get error `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_PACKAGE_CHANGED: installPackageLI]`. I tried to search the error in android source but the error is not meaningfully documented. The following line if from [android source](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageManager.java;l=1940;drc=6c1a4dcfa95c07706e9e5cf734e1327a40012efd):

```
    /**
     * Installation return code: this is passed in the {@link PackageInstaller#EXTRA_LEGACY_STATUS}
     * if the package changed from what the calling program expected.
     *
     * @hide
     */
    @SystemApi
    public static final int INSTALL_FAILED_PACKAGE_CHANGED = -23;
```

But the explanation is vague and I don't know what is the reason for this error.

Comment: Try this adb uninstall <package-name> in android studio terminal and install again and let me know if still you find error

Comment: @YogeshRewani Unfortunately the app is a system app and it's not possible to uninstall it.

Comment: So how you are able to update the system app. can you please share the more details

Comment: Please mention the system app your are trying to update. And also mention where you got the update from.